# web service Threads not starting in IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7.5

I have looked at similar articles on this topic without actually getting a solution to the problem i'm facing.

I have a c# web service that contains two threads and they all started and worked perfectly when tested on the ASP.NET development server on my development machine, which might suggest that the code is in order.

Since I intend to deploy it on IIS 7.5, I decided to test it on a local copy of IIS. On IIS, I noticed that the threads refuse to start. Before I resorted to using threads, I have used System.Timers Timer, and System.Threading Timer with the same behaviour, that is, the Timers worked on my ASP.NET development server but refused to work when tested on IIS. Please, What could be the reason for this and what do I do to solve this bottleneck.

Thanks so much for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I just learnt the hard way that I wasn't supposed to use threads in the web service. After removing the threads, it still worked fine.